# geom_line not outputting connected points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the attached dataframe. I am wanting to create a line graph using ggplot in order to plot Total and Year, with seperate lines for each offence category. I have used the following code, but I feel it is very incorrect as the output does not have any connected lines, it looks more like a vertical line graph. Any help is much appreciated :)
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT1g2.png)

The code I have tried is:
ggplot(data = annual, aes(x = (as.numeric(Year)), y = Total, group = `Offence Category`)) +
geom_line()

Comment: Is 1995 the only year in the dataset?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @jpdugo17 no, the years range from 1995 to 2020. I am hoping to create a new line for each year.